# What changes should be made to the datamodel in power-bi to accommodate the following?

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, datamodel

I have a requirement where I have to display the values in the matrix visual.

The data is like this:

[image]

The "null" value in the level2 and level3 indicate that the score is for that particular Level1.

For example: In line 1, the values for level2 and level3 are null, which indicates that the score1 and score 2 for Level 1 are 3.5 and 3.5 respectively.

There are a total of 3 levels. They should be displayed in a hierarchy, like:

```
Level 1 

            Level 2

                        Level 3.
```

For eg: 2 level hierarchy, it goes like:

```
Level 2             score1           score2

A                     3.5                  3,5
   AA                 3                    3
   AB                 4                    3
   AC                 4                    3

B                     3.2                 3.2
   BA                 3                    4
   BB                 4                    3
```

What changes should I make to the datamodel/column to accomodate this?
The end result should look like this:
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a measure to take level into account.

This isn't very pretty but might give you an idea of how to approach this sort of thing:

```
Score1 Switch = 
VAR CurrentLevel =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        ISINSCOPE ( Table1[Level 3] ), 3,
        ISINSCOPE ( Table1[Level 2] ), 2,
        ISINSCOPE ( Table1[Level 1] ), 1,
        0
    )
VAR CurrentLevelIsBlank =
    SWITCH (
        CurrentLevel,
        3, ISBLANK ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Level 3] ) ),
        2, ISBLANK ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Level 2] ) ),
        1, ISBLANK ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Level 1] ) )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ( CurrentLevelIsBlank ),
        SWITCH (
            CurrentLevel,
            1, CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[score 1] ), ISBLANK ( Table1[Level 2] ) ),
            2, CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[score 1] ), ISBLANK ( Table1[Level 3] ) ),
            3, SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[score 1] )
        )
    )
```

[image: Hierarchy]

**Edit:** A couple of useful references

- https://www.daxpatterns.com/hierarchies/
- https://www.kasperonbi.com/use-isinscope-to-get-the-right-hierarchy-level-in-dax/

Comment: Thanks Alexis. Really appreciate your help. You're awesome :)

Comment: Hi Alexis,I just checked for level3 and it seems to be displaying the same blanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the matrix built-in visual with a hierarchy created for level. Doing so you will get something as described in the question. Below is how it looks in Power BI:

[image: Stepped level matrix]

Below mentioned are the steps to achieve the above:

Create a hierarchy:

1. Right click on column Level 1 ---> New Hierarchy
2. Drag Level 2 and 3 one by one on the Level 1 hierarchy created to get something like below picture:

[image]

Once the hierarchy is created, drop the hierarchy on Rows and the fields score 1 and score 2  under Values in a Matrix visual as shown below:

[image]

Hope this works for you.

Don't forget to vote for the answer if this works.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. But, my requirement is that the first blank row depicts the value for the whole of level1. But, in your approach the value for the column cant be displayed. Please, have a look at the example that I have provided in the question.

Comment: Please, have a look at the image that I have uploaded in the question just now. That is how I want the end result to look like.